# Automorphism group of a graph as a group of matrices

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and $A$ its adjacency matrix. Is it correct to say:

$$\text{Aut}(G)=\{PAP^T:P\text{ is a permutation matrix}\}$$

I believe so, but I have never seen it written this way.

If so, then there must be permutation matrices $P_1,P_2$ with $P_1\ne P_2$ and an adjacency matrix of a graph such that $P_1AP_1^T=P_2AP_2^T$ for otherwise $\text{Aut}(G)=S_n$.

For example if $G$ is a cycle on $4$ vertices say $1-2-3-4-1$. Its automorphism group is $D_4$. What would be an example of $P_1,P_2$ in that case?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The set you've given is the set of all adjacency matrices that describe graphs isomorphic to $G$.  The set you're looking for is the set of all *isomorphisms* (so permutations rather than graphs) that map the graph to *itself*.

What you should have instead is something like
$$
\text{Aut}(G)=\{P: PAP^T = A \text{ and } P\text{ is a permutation matrix}\}
$$

---

For your example: take $G= C_4$, with matrix
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
0&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0
}
$$
Consider
$$
P_1 = 
\pmatrix
{
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0
}, \quad
P_2 = 
\pmatrix{
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
}
$$
$P_1 \in \text{Aut}(G)$ since $P_1AP_1^T = A$. However,
$$
P_2AP_2^T = 
\pmatrix{
0&1&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0
} \neq A
$$
So, $P_2 \notin \text{Aut}(G)$

Comment: What is $PAP^T\cong A$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, that should just be $=$.  Fixed.

Comment: See my latest edit